# Is there anyway i can detect "~" by using GetAsyncKeyState?

Tags: c++, winapi

By using `GetAsyncKeyState` it cannot detect `'~'` button (at the top left of the keyboard).
So there is any way to detect this button?
Or should I use another command ?

By the way I am using c++

Comment: Please show what you tried. Why you cannot detect that key?

Comment: How did you use `GetAsyncKeyState()` trying to detect it? Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState( VK_OEM_3 )` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual key code of "~" is `VK_OEM_3`.

More virtual key codes can be referenced:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

How to use it, please refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

A simple example：

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  BOOL OEM_3 = FALSE;
  while (1)
  {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_OEM_3) < 0 && OEM_3 == false)
    {
      //Press down
      OEM_3 = true;
      cout << "Press down" << endl;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_OEM_3) >= 0 && OEM_3 == true)
    {
      //Release
      OEM_3 = false;
      cout << "Release" << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on the keyboard layout. Asker clearly has the `~` key at top left of the keyboard which suggests a US keyboard. However, there is also the shift state to deal with on that layout. And what about other layouts? Finally, the opposite of `< 0` is in fact `>= 0` and not `== 0` as your answer indicates.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure if you've read my first link, which clearly indicates it. VK_OEM_3  Windows 2000: for the US standard keyboard, the `~` key，Also, I tested my current code, which can test the button status of `~`

Comment: Key is down if return value is < 0, key is up if return value is >= 0. Read the docs to understand why.

Comment: @nabangkae And don't forget to mark it if the answer is what you need, in order to help people with the same problems.